# Chrome extension to automate bookmark delete for current site

Tags: chrome, bookmark

I am looking for a Chrome Extension that will find and delete all bookmarks that match the current Chrome tab web address.  After deletion, it would also be nice to automatically close the current tab.

If you're like me, you have a lot of Chrome bookmarks and you find it difficult to review and remove unwanted bookmarks.  The idea is to open multiple bookmarks in tabs (this feature is already available in Chrome) and review each and decide if you wish to keep the bookmark or delete it.  If you wish to delete the bookmark you would execute the suggested Chrome Extension (preferably with a keystroke).  If you wish to keep the bookmark, simply press CTRL-w to close the tab and move on to the next tab.

The gold star in the address bar indicates that the current page is bookmarked.  So, I can click it, then click remove to remove the bookmark... then I can close the tab and move on.  However, I would like to customize and streamline the process of removing my bookmarks with a custom extension.

I am a developer, but I lack the background in Chrome extension development.  Perhaps an experienced Chrome extension developer could create this relatively simple javascript code OR at least get me started.

Comment: I have a chrome/firefox extension to auto close tabs that is opensource: [Tab Close Gold](https://github.com/mukunku/Tab-Close-Gold/tree/master). The readme has info on how to get it running locally. Maybe that would be a good starting point for you?